# Querying records based on join not returning expected results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am trying to write a query in MySQL that retrieves `subscription` records, based on the `expiration` column of joined `transaction`s.

A `subscription` can have 0 or more `transaction` records, and `transaction.expiration` can be NULL or a Datetime. I want to retrieve subscriptions that have expired in the last 6 hours, but only if the subscription doesn't also have a transaction with a NULL expiration (this would mean the subscription does not expire).

Here's my query right now:

```sql
SELECT subscription.id
  FROM app_subscriptions AS subscription
  JOIN (
           SELECT subscription_id
             FROM app_transactions
            WHERE (
                        expiration >= %s
                    AND expiration <= %s
                    AND expiration IS NOT NULL
                  )
         GROUP BY subscription_id
       ) as transaction
    ON subscription.id = transaction.subscription_id
 ORDER BY subscription.id DESC
```

The datetime comparisons are set using PHP (formatted like 0000-00-00 00:00:00)

Testing this against two subscriptions:

- The first has a single transaction with an expired expiration. This should be in the results.
- The second has two transactions, one with an expired expiration, and one with a NULL expiration. This should not be in the results.

  With the above query, both subscriptions are still returned, when I only want the first one. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Happy to provide more info!

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to retrieve subscriptions that have expired in the last 6 hours.

Why not just do something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.subscription_id
FROM app_transactions t
WHERE t.expiration > now() - interval 6 hour;
```

If expirations can be in the future as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.subscription_id
FROM app_transactions t
WHERE t.expiration > now() - interval 6 hour AND
      t.expiration < now();
```

EDIT:

Your comment requires a small tweak to this query, basically `GROUP BY` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT t.subscription_id
FROM app_transactions t
WHERE (t.expiration > now() - interval 6 hour AND
       t.expiration < now()
      ) OR
      t.expiration IS NULL
GROUP BY t.sucscription_id
HAVING SUM( t.expiration IS NULL ) = 0;  -- no NULL ones
```

Comment: Hey! This looks real nice. Is there any way to update this so that it excludes any subscriptions that have transactions with `null` expirations, even if that same subscription has another transaction with a qualifying expiration?